# Nest auth: An error occured. Connecting to xx is currently unavailable

Tags: authorization, nest-api

My app has been running fine for several months, but since yesterday when me or someone else tries to log into the app using the webview it gives an error:

> An error occured. Connecting to *appname* is currently unavailable.
>   Please contact *me* for more information.

This happens after you fill in your email/password and press on Accept.

Does anyone else experience this issue, or know a way to solve it?

Comment: Out of interest vixez, what is your app? (is it available for general download?)

Comment: The app is N10. It is available for free in the Windows Store: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/n10/9nblggh16nk8

Comment: Looks like a nice app - sadly I'm getting the error message you mentioned in your question. Hope that you can get it reviewed by Nest quickly and more quota added.

Comment: Thanks, last time I asked for it to be reviewed it took about a month. So I hope it'll be okay next month..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users will get this error message when you have exceeded your quota. If you look at your product on developer.nest.com you will see that the limit on tokens has been met.

In order to continue to add users, you will need to submit your product for review by Nest. Once approved, your token limit will be increased.

Comment: That will probably be the case, I've put it up for review with Nest. Thanks.